# How to capitalize all the chars of string after . like mobile keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My requirement is not only capitalize first character of string, there is a paragraph and I want capitalize first character of each string like mobile device keyboard.

I've tried below solutions but that doesn't fulfill my requirement:

```
$('#test').blur(function(event) {
 var value = $(this).val();

 var output = "";

 output = value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);

});
```

above code only doing first character capitalize.

**Sample input:**

> **l**orem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. **l**orem ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.**t**hat's it!

**Expected output:**

> **L**orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. **L**orem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.**T**hat's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression: match either the start of the string or a period followed by spaces, then match an alphabetical character, and use a replacer function to call `toUpperCase` on that character. To also correctly replace letters that come after `?` and `!`s as well as `.`, use a character set `[.?!]`:

```js
const input = `lorem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. lorem ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.that's it!`;
const cleaned = input.replace(
  /(^|\[.?!] *)([a-z])/g,
  (_, g1, g2) => g1 + g2.toUpperCase()
);
console.log(cleaned);
```

To *not* replace ellipsis, you can match one more character before the `.` in the first group:

```js
const input = `foo bar. bar baz... baz buzz? buzz foo`;
const cleaned = input.replace(
  /(^|(?:[?!]|[^.]\.) *)([a-z])/g,
  (_, g1, g2) => g1 + g2.toUpperCase()
);
console.log(cleaned);
```

The pattern

```
(^|(?:[?!]|[^.]\.) *)([a-z])
```

means:

- `(^|(?:[?!]|[^.]\.) *)` - Capture in 1st group:

  - `^` - Beginning of string, or:
  - `(?:[?!]|[^.]\.)` - Match the end of a previous sentence: either

    - `[?!]` - Question or exclamation mark, or
    - `[^.]\.` - Non-period, followed by period
  - `*` Followed by any number of space characters
- `([a-z])` - Capture in 2nd group any alphabetical character

Then

```
  (_, g1, g2) => g1 + g2.toUpperCase()
```

replaces with the first group, concatenated with the second group lowercased.

Comment: Thanks for reply! is there any way to do without regular expression ?

Comment: Possible, but regular expressions are *very* suited for this sort of thing - searching text for matches and replacing appropriate substrings with something else. I'd much prefer a RE to anything else.

Comment: @Nimeshkhatri here's a method that doesn't rely on regular expressions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738294/how-to-capitalize-all-the-chars-of-string-after-like-mobile-keyboard/53738329#53738329

Comment: For me it works only the first L. My text is containing also ellipsis consisting of three dots. I wouldn't change to upper case after these suspension points. Do You have any suggestion for that?

Comment: @deblocker See edit with pattern explanation. What do you mean, the first L doesn't work? Check the snippet - the first L appears to be capitalized as desired

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
var input = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.That's it!";
    
console.log( input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.slice(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match use the `String#replace()` method with the following regular expression:

```
/\.\s*\w/
```

combined with a custom replace callback that capitalizes the matched string to achieve this. The basic idea here is to capitalize any substring that is the first letter directly following a full stop character (ie `\.`). The regular expression also take into account cases where zero or more whitespaces (ie `\s*`) occur between the full stop and the next letter character (ie `\w`):

```js
var input = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.That's it!";

var result = input.replace(/\.\s*\w/, function(match) {
  return match.toUpperCase();
});

console.log('Regular expression based approach', result);
```

Also, I noticed in a comment that you asked about a method that did not require regular expressions. Although regular expressions are generally preferred from problems like this, the following shows a non-re based approach:

```js
const input = `lorem ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. lorem ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.that's it!`;

console.log('Non regular expression based approach:',

input
.split('.')
.map((sentence) => {

  for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {

    if (sentence[i] !== ' ') {
    
      sentence = sentence.substr(0, i) + sentence[i].toUpperCase() + sentence.substr(i + 1);      
      break;
    }
  }

  return sentence
})
.join('.')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let paragraph = document.querySelector('#test').textContent;

let result = paragraph.split('.')
    .map(sentence => sentence.trim())
    .map(sentence => {
        sentence = sentence.replace(sentence[0], sentence[0].toUpperCase()) + sentence.slice(1);
        return sentence;
    });


console.log(result.join('. '));
```